# Is it possible to replace child element tag within a parent tag?

Tags: html, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I will describe my problem in a given HTML format:

```
<Doc>
  <test>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Test 1</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Test 2</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>75%</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>86%</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </test>
</Doc>
```

Now as you noticed there are 2 `<tr></tr>` tags, i want to change/replace, ONLY the FIRST `<tr></tr>` tag (that contains Test 1 and Test 2) to "`<th></th>`". BTW, there are several occurrences for `<test></test>` within the `<Doc></Doc>` tag and several occurrences for `<tr></tr>` within the `<test></test>` tags like as shown below:

```
<Doc>
  <test>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Quiz 1</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Quiz 2</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Exam 1</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>24 out of 50</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>16 out of 50</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>77/100</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </test>
</Doc>
```

So far i've got this: `(<table>\s+<tr>\s+)(<td>)\s+<p>.*</p>\s+(</td>)` i don't know how to get the right mix as i am new to regex. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Is there any particular need to use regex here? It may not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: Yeah, thats why im asking if it is possible for just regex to be used. Anyway thank you.

Comment: A [classic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1171702).

Comment: Hmmp. i guess its not possible :(

Comment: Thank you guys, if anyone out there wants to try it out and share your thought feel free to drop by, hence edit anything in this post if needed.